# Django - limiting query results resulting TypeError

Tags: django

I inserted 3 items in the database, and the following code can get all the 3 items:

```
Movie.objects.all().order_by('first_show')
```

But when I add the limit to it:

```
Movie.objects.all().order_by('first_show')[0,1]
```

It gives the TypeError exception:

[image]

Why adding limit causes exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `:` in slicing instead of `,`:

```
Movie.objects.all().order_by('first_show')[0:1]
```